# Execution stuck when calling undetected_chromedriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to use the `undetected_chromedriver.v2` package in Python Anaconda. My code goes like this:

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
ucoptions = uc.ChromeOptions()
print('1')
ucoptions.add_argument('--no-first-run')
print('2')
driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options = ucoptions)
print('3')
```

In Anaconda Spyder, it works well if I use the `F9` key to step into every single line of code and is able to open the Chrome browser normally as expected.

However, whenever I use the `F5` key to run the whole file, it always get stuck in the `driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options = ucoptions)` line and can only print out "1" and "2" on my screen.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Many thanks!